# CSS doesn't work on HTML element

Tags: javascript, html, css, dom

I have small piece of code written in JavaScript and CSS.

The problem is that the 'div column' is not affected by the CSS code. The border and background should appear and their color should be red.

What am I missing?

Here is the code:

https://codepen.io/orc2000/pen/VdEXVY

```js
var text = "";
text += '<div class="row">';

text += '<div class="wrapper-elem"';
text += '<div class="column">';
text += '<h4> Column 1' + '</h4>';
text += '<img src="SomePicture 1"' + 'width="100" height="100" align = "center" > ';
text += '<p>' + 'Price 20' + '</p>';
text += '<p>' + 'DryFood' + '</p>';
text += '</div>';
text += '</div>';

text += '<div class="wrapper-elem"';
text += '<div class="column">';
text += '<h4> Column 2' + '</h4>';
text += '<img src = "SomePicture 2"' + 'width="100" height="100" align = "center" > ';
text += '<p>' + 'Pret 10' + '</p>';
text += '<p>' + 'DryFood' + '</p>';
text += '</div>';
text += '</div>';

text += '</div>';

document.getElementById("delta").innerHTML = text;
```

```css
* {
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

/* Create two equal columns that floats next to each other */
.wrapper-elem {
  float: left;
  width: 50 %;
  background-color: white;
  padding: 10px;
  border: 2px solid blue;
}

.column {
  border: 5px solid red;
  background-color: red;
}


/* Clear floats after the columns  */
.row: after {
  content: "";
  display: table;
  clear: both;
}
```

```html
<div id="delta"></div>
```

Comment: Consider using template literals when creating multiple lines of strings. https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Template_literals

Comment: Your "wrapper-elem" `<div>` is missing its `>` *edit* both of them

Comment: Oh, such a stupid mistake :(. Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You had:

- **some missing HTML tag parts** (2 closing `>`), when you constructed the HTML using JavaScript
- **a space in the CSS** (`width: 50_%`)

```js
var text = `
  <div class="row">
    <div class="wrapper-elem">
      <div class="column">
        <h4>Column 1</h4>
        <img src="SomePicture 1" width="100" height="100" align="center">
        <p>Price 20</p>
        <p>DryFood</p>
      </div>
    </div>      
    <div class="wrapper-elem">
    <div class="column">
      <h4>Column2</h4>
      <img src="SomePicture 2"width="100" height="100" align="center">
      <p>Pret 10</p>
      <p>DryFood</p>
    </div>
  </div>
`;

document.getElementById("delta").innerHTML = text;
```

```css
* {
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

/* Create two equal columns that floats next to each other */
.wrapper-elem {
  float: left;
  width: 50%;
  background-color: white;
  padding: 10px;
  border: 2px solid blue;
}

.column {
  border: 5px solid red;
  background-color: red;
}

/* Clear floats after the columns  */
.row: after {
  content: "";
  display: table;
  clear: both;
}
```

```html
<html>
  <head>
    <title>Test Page</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="test.css">
  </head>
  <body>
    <div id="delta"> </div>
    <script src="test.js"></script>
  </body>
</html>
```

Answer (score -2):

It's better to call your js, after DOM will be ready:)
Small refactoring

```
"use strict"

  function generateText() {
    var text = "";
    text += '<div class="row">';

    text += '<div class="wrapper-elem"';
    text += '<div class="column">';
    text += '<h4> Column 1' + '</h4>';
    text += '<img src="SomePicture 1"' + 'width="100" height="100" align="center">';
    text += '<p>' + 'Price 20' + '</p>';
    text += '<p>' + 'DryFood' + '</p>';
    text += '</div>';
    text += '</div>';

    text += '<div class="wrapper-elem"';
    text += '<div class="column">';
    text += '<h4> Column 2' + '</h4>';
    text += '<img src = "SomePicture 2"' + 'width="100" height="100" align="center">';
    text += '<p>' + 'Pret 10' + '</p>';
    text += '<p>' + 'DryFood' + '</p>';
    text += '</div>';
    text += '</div>';

    text += '</div>';

    return text;
  }

  document.addEventListener("DOMContentLoaded", function(){
    document.getElementById("delta").innerHTML = generateText();
  });
```

Comment: Thank you, I didn't knew that.

Comment: The original code had the JS after the last element anyway

Comment: It's bad practice do like that:)